# Accessing contact name, phone and email using picker without deprecated code

Tags: android

I am trying to use the default contact picker so the user can choose a contact where I can populate form with Name, phone numbers and email.

I am using the following for picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, GlobalVar.GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The problem is when I get activity results. All what I can see on SO is deprecated API such as managerQuery (answers back from 2010). When I got to the android website then it talks about populating listview with contacts details.

I am confused. I don't want to build my own listview. I want to use the default picker and just grab the above info.

Any help, working example or at least a pointer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like below.

```
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1000;

    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

In ActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {startActivityForReslut
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_CONTACT:
                contactInfo(data);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
    }
}
```

Function to pick contact information :

```
private void contactInfo(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String name = null;
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        Toast.makeText(this,name + "," +phoneNo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Reference : http://stackandroid.com/tutorial/contact-picker-using-intent-android-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you so much .how would grab the email address ?